# Postgres docker container logs FATAL role does not exist every 5 seconds

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I have a postgres container running on a digital ocean droplets. I can connect to it normally, but when I check the logs I can see that this log appear every 5 seconds:

[image]

I'm sure I don't have any other services trying to connect to it recursively, so I don't understand what causes this log. Maybe it's because in my Docker compose file I specify POSTGRES_USER as a different user instead of postgres?
Also when I use psql to list all my user with \du, I can only see one user, which is the one I specify in the docker compose file, and there's no "postgres" user.
Can you help me understand where this log come from?

Comment: If your container is reachable from the Internet, then it might be random bots trying to hack you

Comment: If you add %h to your log_line_prefix, or turn on log_connections, or do both, then you will at least know what IP it is coming from.

Comment: @jjanes oh thank you for your suggestion! I added %u %h to log_line_prefix and the user is postgres and the host is an ip address that turns out to be from digital ocean when use ip check service. Do you know what that mean?

Comment: No, don't know from experience. Speculating, maybe DO has some kind of monitoring in place--although it would be weird for them to be monitoring a database you set up and ran yourself on hardware rented from them, which is I assume what you are doing here (as opposed to using a database managed directly by DO).  Or maybe some miscreant has either rented a server on DO, or compromised one, and is now using it to attack you.  If it is close to a steady rhythm of 5 seconds, that sounds more like monitoring rather than hacking.

Comment: @jjanes thank you. Guess I should contact DO to find out